# C++ Passing a reference to an anonymous structure - can you?

Tags: c++, structure, anonymous

Using the structure shown below, I can use it like this for example.

```
NMEADecodedSentence s;
auto & gga = s.GGA;
auto alt = gga.Alt;
```

But is it possible to pass a reference to an anonymous structure to a function such as:

```
SomeFunc(gga);
```

If so, what would the function signature look like?  My thoughts are no you cant without naming the structures but I just wanted to know if there was some clever way of doing it that I didn't know!

```
struct NMEADecodedSentence
    {
        GNSSSentenceType Type;
        GNSSTalkerId TalkerId;
        union
        {
            struct
            {
                char Time[10];          // UTC time - hhmmss.ss
                char Lat[13];           // Latitude (degrees & minutes) - ddmm.mmmmm
                char NS;                // North/South indicator
                char Long[14];          // Longitude (degrees & minutes) - dddmm.mmmmm
                char EW;                // East/West indicator
                uint8_t Quality;        // Quality indicator for position fix
                uint8_t NumSV;          // Number of satellites used (0-12)
                float HDOP;             // Horizontal Dilution of Precision
                float Alt;              // Altitude above mean sea level - meters
            }GGA;
            struct // Recommended minimum data
            {
                char Time[10];          // UTC time - hhmmss.ss
                char Status;            // Status, V = Navigation receiver warning, A = Data valid
                char Lat[13];           // Latitude (degrees & minutes) - ddmm.mmmmm
                char NS;                // North/South indicator
                char Long[14];          // Longitude (degrees & minutes) - dddmm.mmmmm
                char EW;                // East/West indicator
                float Spd;              // Speed over ground - knots
                float COG;              // Course over ground - degrees
                char Date[7];           // UTC Date - ddmmyy
            }RMC;
            struct // Course over ground and ground speed
            {
                float COGT;             // Course over ground (true) - degrees
                float COGM;             // Course over ground (magnetic) - degrees
                float Kph;              // Speed over ground - kph
            }VTG;
        };
    };
```

Comment: Do you want to use `auto` in a function declaration?

Comment: to paraphrase: You _can_ do this, but **should** you? Is omitting the name in the declaration really worth the extra boilerplate in the receiving functions? What do you gain from it, really?

Comment: @underscore_d it is possible that declaration is some kind of library or vendor-supplied code, so he may not risk to change it ( always bad idea to edit headers that have external source)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
void f(decltype(NMEADecodedSentence::GGA)& gga)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Yes, that did indeed exactly answer my question.  Good thinking!  Thanks...

Answer (score 5):

You can do this, if compiler supports decltype feature (part of standard, but we all know how it goes..)

```
char foo2(decltype (NMEADecodedSentence::GGA) & param)
{
     return param.EW; 
}
```

`decltype` is very useful for template building. `NMEADecodedSentence::GGA` as a name of non-static member of class is usable in this case.

Open template is usable, but is type unsafe, because you may try to offer anything that contains same fields used in function instead of `NMEADecodedSentence::GGA`.That can be a feature or a misfeature of architecture.

You can protect template like this:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
char foo( T &a )
{
  static_assert(std::is_same<T,decltype (NMEADecodedSentence::GGA)>::value || 
                std::is_same<T,decltype (NMEADecodedSentence::RMC)>::value, 
                "Wrong type of foo() argument" );
  return a.EW;  
}
```

`static_assert` would produce a compile time error (that's why it is "static"), if you provide `foo` with argument of different type: `std::is_same<>::value` would be false.

Note, that you can do this as well:

```
struct  GGAType : public decltype (NMEADecodedSentence::GGA)
{
};
```

but aforementioned template will not accept argument of this type without a fix  to the static_assert expression. `foo2()` would work.